# Filter by timestamp in nested fields in Kibana 4

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana-4

Is it possible to create a mapping (e.g. nested) that allows to filter by individual timestamps of orders, where the orders are nested properties of the indexed documents (products)?

In other words, I would like to define a time range in Kibana and receive a list of matching products that contain any orders matching the given time range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I knew, Kibana can not handle with nested Json, so first you need to change it to standard Json.

Answer (score 1):

As per your question:-  I would like to define a time range in Kibana and receive a list of matching products that contain any orders matching the given time range.

For this you can load the data in Kibana & filter the time in Kibana UI using Time Filter which will show you the orders matching the time range using the timestamp field as mentioned.